# setAttribute doesn't work in IE6

Tags: javascript

how to set element attribute with javascript in IE6..? It seems `setAttribute` doesn't work. I really need to do it on the fly. Thanks.

***Code***

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
    menuItems = document.getElementById("menu").childNodes; 
    for (i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++)
    { 
        if (menuItems[i].className != "blue") 
            menuItems[i].setAttribute('onmouseover', 'HoverMenu(this)'); 
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: I've used `setAttribute` on IE6 and it works. Maybe something else is causing a problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*(Most of the below was before the OP clarified they were setting an event handler; left the list of other issues in case others find them useful)*

IE6 makes a mess of several aspects of `setAttribute`. Without knowing the exact problem you were dealing with (*this was before the edit inidicating it was an event handler*), it's hard to be sure whether that's really the problem, but here are a couple of known issues:

#### You can't use `setAttribute` to set event handlers

It's best to set event handlers using the reflected property or with [`addEventListener`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventTarget-addEventListener) [standard] / [`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343(VS.85).aspx) [IE], not `setAttribute` (and you *can't* use `setAttribute` on IE).

So, any of these will work:

```
// Using reflected property
theElement.onclick = yourFunction;

// Using DOM2 standard addEventListener; note it's "click", not "onclick"
theElement.addEventListener("click", yourFunction, false);

// IE's non-standard alternative to addEventListener
theElement.attachEvent("onclick", yourFunction);
```

...not

```
// This doesn't work on IE (at least)
theElement.setAttribute("onclick", "yourFunction();");
```

The `addEventListener` / `attachEvent` way of doing this is cool for other reasons: You can have *multiple* event listeners on the same event of an element. You can't do that using the reflected property.

So for your specific situation:

```
menuItems = document.getElementById("menu").childNodes; 
for (i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++)
{ 
    if (menuItems[i].className != "blue") {
        menuItems[i].onmouseover = function() {
            HoverMenu(this);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Certain attributes need their modified names

**`class`**

The correct way to set the class attribute is to use the reflected property `className`:

```
// Correct, cross-browser way. Works on IE6+, all versions of
// Chrome, etc. Completely reliable.
theElement.className = "new set of classes";
```

or on modern browsers (so, not IE6!) you can use `classList`.

One of IE6's many `setAttribute` bugs is that this doesn't work:

```
// Should also work, but fails on IE6 (and probably some other old versions)
theElement.setAttribute("class", "new set of classes");
```

Instead, IE6 (and probably a couple of other versions) make you use `"className"` instead of `"class"`, even though that makes no sense whatsoever. The reflected *property* has the name `className` because it used to be that in JavaScript, you couldn't use reserved words (like `class` or `for` or `if`) as property literals (`obj.class` was invalid). That's not been true for a while now (ECMAScript 5 fixed it), but that's why the reflected property is `className`, not `class.`

But since `setAttribute` takes a *string*, it should accept the proper name of the attribute. The fact it doesn't is just an IE bug (and one they've fixed in modern versions of IE if they're not in [in]compatibility mode).

**`for`**

Similarly, to set the `for` attribute (for instance, on `label`s), one uses the `htmlFor` reflected property:

```
// Correct, cross-browser way. Works on IE6+, all versions of
// Chrome, etc. Completely reliable.
theLabel.htmlFor = "id-of-field";
```

On any non-broken browser, you can also use `setAttribute`:

```
// Should also work, but fails on IE6 (and probably some other old versions)
theLabel.setAttribute("for", "id-of-field");
```

...but not on IE6, it wants `"htmlFor"` instead of `"for"` for the same reason it wants `"className"` rather than `"class"` (e.g, because it's broken).

[This page](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/08/bug-242-setattribute-doesnt-always-work.html) has quite a list of attributes that are problematic with IE.

#### `setAttribute` can't be used to set the `style` attribute

...you have to use the `style` property instead; but to be fair, that's usually a more convenient way. Example: This won't work on IE:

```
theElement.setAttribute("style", "color: blue"); // Doesn't work on IE
```

...but this will:

```
myElement.style.color = "blue";
```

#### Slightly OT: Look at libraries

JavaScript libraries like [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) will make most of the above a lot easier and smooth out differences amongst browsers if you go through their APIs.

Comment: I've changed to menuItems[i].onmouseover = "HoverMenu(this)"; but still no luck.

Comment: just a point on this you don't have to set it as a string. It would be more like:

menuItems[i].onmouseover = HoverMenu;

you can access the menu item in the method by using the this keyword.

Comment: @spinon: Agreed, when I was writing my answer originally they hadn't said they were setting an event handler! So it was a bit general to start. :-)

Comment: @Jeaffrey: It should be just `menuItems[i].onmouseover = function() { HoverMenu(this); };` (or just `menuItems[i].onmouseover = HoverMenu;` if you update `HoverMenu` to use this rather than an argument). I've reformatted my answer and added an update of your specific code.

Comment: menuItems[i].onmouseover = function() { HoverMenu(this); }; is PERFECTO! :P Thank you Mr. Tj.

It had not worked because of the IETester v0.4.4! I don't know it doesn't show latest changes of your code after error on your code occurred even you have refreshed it :( *I don't have IE6 on my Win7*

Comment: @Jeaffrey: Good deal, glad that helped.

Answer (score 1):

I would really look at jquery. It has all the functionality that works with IE6 and this would be so much easier than the code you have here. It would look like this:

```
menuItems = $("#menu")[0].childNodes; 
$.each(menuItems, function()
{
    var item = $(this);
    if (item.attr("className") != "blue")
        item.mouseover(HoverMenu);
}
```

This code might need to be tweaked a little as I am just writing from memory.

I say easier because what you are trying to do in setting events like this varies based on browser and can be a headache to setup. But with jquery it is all done for you.

Comment: `item.mouseover = HoverMenu;` should be `item.bind("mouseover", HoverMenu);` or `item.hover(HoverMenu, $.noop);`

Comment: Here is the jquery doc that says this should work:
http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Comment: No, `mouseover` on a jQuery object is a *function*: `item.mouseover(HoverMenu);` It's just shorthand for `item.bind("mouseover", HoverMenu);`

Comment: T.J you're right I'm sorry. I couldn't figure out what you were talking about as to why this was wrong because I write it all the time. Then when looking at what you wrote right now I realized I was confusing the = sign for the function declaration I do inside the method call.

So it should have been
item.mouseover(HoverMenu)'

or like I usually write it
item.mouseover(function() { /* some code */ });

Sorry I wasn't seeing where the disconnect was.