# jquery setting 'onmouseover' attr doesn't seem to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover

I seem to be unable to change the onmouseover attribute of a div using jquery.  In the code below, lines 1 and 3 work fine but line 2 does nothing.

```
window.parent.$('#note' + appid + dbid).html('<img src="images/note_gray.png">');
window.parent.$('#note' + appid + dbid).attr('onmouseover','testestestsetset');
window.parent.$('#note' + appid + dbid).attr('title', 'testdata');
```

Using Chrome (13.0.772.0 dev-m) watching the developer tools.  I see the two changes immediately as I should, the onmouseover never does anything.

The .net code uses onmouseover to do some weird javascript hover thing.  I don't want to go back and change all that functionality, so when I update a record I want it to change the hover tip to reflect the new data, without doing a page postback.  This is why I am using onmouseover and trying to change it from jquery so please don't ask "Why don't you use x instead".  Thanks.

---EDIT----

If it helps, this is what it looks like in HTML from the generated page that I am building edit functionality for.  The original code uses a javascript function called "Tip" to generate a hovertip.  This was written by someone else.  I am doing edit modals for the page.  When you submit a change, I want it to change the tooltip.

```
<div id="note1009872" class="dbnote" onmouseover="Tip('No Notes...')" onmouseout="UnTip()" title="testempty"><img src="images/note.png"></div>
```

Comment: :O never ever ever ever ever set javascript events as attributes, specially with jQuery! Use `.bind("mouseover",function(){})`

Comment: Since you don't want suggestions for better alternatives, what exactly is your question then?

Comment: 1. Consider JCOC611's comment. Strongly. Drink some coffee and read it again. 2, if you really want to use attr, try `testestestsetset();`. I can't promise that will fix it because I don't want to try.

Comment: @Sparky672: I explained my predicament and respectfully made a request.  Was it really necessary to downvote my question?

Comment: @Scott Beeson:  -1 ... you specifically asked people not to make helpful suggestions and I don't see a **"?"** anywhere in your posting.  So again, **what is your question?!**

Comment: @Sparky672... see the part where it says "Lines 1 and 3 work but line 2 does nothing"?  I'm sorry I should have specifically said "How do I make line 2 do something" but I thought most people could draw that conclusion.  I have edited the question to elaborate on WHY I need to use onmouseover.  If it still doesn't make sense to you, please just move on and let someone else try.

Comment: You know it's really disheartening that I'm obviously new here, and new to jquery/javascript and on my second question I get a response like this.  I'm not mad, just very discouraged.

Comment: And I did try .bind("mouseover","Tip('test')"); with no luck.

Comment: @Scott Beeson: Sparky's downvote is perfectly reasonable - you essentially said "I'm doing it the way I'm doing it, it doesn't work, but I demand a solution that doesn't require me to change anything." The correct approach, as agreed upon by the up-voted comments (and any answer I'd post), is not to use the onmouseover attribute. You should be binding the event properly.

Comment: @Scott Beeson: `.bind('mouseover', function () { ... })`.

Comment: Scott, haven't properly read the question, but regarding your last comment, `.bind()` is not like native attributes, you need to pass a function, not a string that will be `eval`ed. So instead of `.bind("mouseover","Tip('test')");` you would have `.bind("mouseover", function(){ Tip("test"); );`

Comment: I'm assuming that doesn't work because as far as this page is concerned there is no function called Tip() as it's part of the parent page.  I'm sorry for all the confusion here, apparently my request was misunderstood, I want to make it work, but I come to these sites and people usually say "Don't use mouseover, you should use css hover instead" or something like that.  I HAVE to keep using mouseover due to legacy code.

Comment: This is a slight tangent, but you really shouldn't be creating 3 jQuery objects, when you can simply chain them: `window.parent.$('#note' + appid + dbid).html(...).attr(...).attr(...);`

Comment: As for the technical confusion on my part (being totally new to javascript), when viewing the HTML I didn't assume there was a difference between changing the title attribute or the onmouseover attribute (and I still don't quite understand why you can't do it that way, but C'est la vie...)

Comment: @Scott B - Check out my answer ... It will effectively do what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to bind an event property to a string.  That isn't going to get you far.

You need to bind it to a function, whether it is one that sits in the global namespace or is a closure:

```
window.parent.$('#note' + appid + dbid).mouseover(function(){testestestsetset()});
```

Or:

```
window.parent.$('#note' + appid + dbid).mouseover(testestestsetset);
```

---

Ok, turns out that you can bridge across frames like this, but that your execution space must remain in the calling frame unless named:

```
window.parent.$('#note' + appid + dbid).mouseover(function() {
        window.parent.Tip('Some Tip...')
});
```

OR:

```
window.parent.$('#bar').get(0).addEventListener('mouseover',
            function(){window.parent.Tip('Some Tip...')});
```

I've got sample code working from two iFrames and have tested it out.

Comment: This doesn't work.  I'm assuming because the function testestestsetest (or actually Tip()) is part of the parent page...

Comment: What's up with the -1?

Anyway, if you need to access something in the global namespace's, you could consider sending a closure with an anonymous function.  I'll add that example.

Comment: also, Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'onmouseover'

Comment: What is the testestestestes? is that function or just stuff that will break the script as in improper string? Just curious ;)

Comment: The actual function is Tip('text goes here')

Comment: small typo...The jquery function here should be `mouseover` and not `onmouseover`.  This explains Scott's "has no method" error.

Comment: @scott - See my updated answer.  I actually went and built two vanilla pages and tested this for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the actual code behind, why not consider adding the following line in either your `Page_Load()` method or other such appropriate methods as are available:

```
myPanel.Attributes.Remove("onmouseover");
```

This assumes that "myPanel" is the `asp:Panel` object you have on your page.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery uses the `.setAttribute()` method to set attribute values, which [does not work reliably for getting/setting "traditional" event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163212/setattribute-doesnt-work-in-ie6). To change the traditional event handler, you should do so directly instead of using jQuery:

```
var noteElem = window.parent.document.getElementById('note' + appid + dbid);
noteElem.innerHTML='<img src="images/note_gray.png">';
noteElem.onmouseover = 'testestestsetset';
noteElem.title = 'testdata';
```

There is a way to [use jQuery to locate the element](http://api.jquery.com/get/) (or [iterate over multiple elements](http://api.jquery.com/each/)), but jQuery is not of much use in the code snippet you posted.

Comment: sigh... this doesn't work either.  I guess I'll redo all the hover tip stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the inline `onmouseover`/`onmouseout` and use ***[hover()](http://api.jquery.com)*** like in this ***[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CodeMaverick/FTCAH/)***:

```
window.parent.$('#note' + appid + dbid)
    .html('<img src="images/note_gray.png">')
    .attr("title", "testdata")
    .removeAttr("onmouseover")
    .removeAttr("onmouseout")
    .hover(function() {

         // replaces onmouseover
         Tip("new test");

    }, function() {

         // replaces onmouseout
         UnTip();

    });
```